# How to not call any api endpoints if firebase token is expired in React app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebaseui, react-context

I am using firebase-ui-react in a React app for authentication, but the problem is that if someone open the app and don't do any activity up to an hour and after one hour click on a link, all the endpoints get called several times until the the app crash.
the index.jsx looks like this:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/react";
import store from "./Redux/store";
import App from "./App";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";
import { AuthProvider } from "./Containers/Auth/AuthProvider";
import * as firebaseconfig from "./deployment_config.json";

const fbconfig =
  firebaseconfig.default[process.env.REACT_APP_ENV_NAME][
    process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT
  ];

Sentry.init({ dsn: fbconfig.SENTRY_DSN });
ReactGA.initialize(fbconfig.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_TRACKING);

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <AuthProvider fbconfig={fbconfig}>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

the App.jsx looks like:

```js
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./Containers/Auth/AuthProvider";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
//lots of other imports


const App = (props) => {
  const { location } = props;
  const { user, accessTokenExpired, loading, userRole, uiConfig } = useContext(
    AuthContext
  );

  toast.configure();
  const [checkSession, setCheckSession] = useState(false);
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(true);
  const change_body = useSelector((state) => state.Common.change_body);
  const ErrorStatusState = useSelector(
    (state) => state.GetGlobalError.ErrorCode
  );
  const configdata = useSelector((state) => state.GetConfig.data);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(GetConfig());
  }, []);

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => response,
    (error) => {

      if (error.message === "Network Error") {
        setCheckSession(true);
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  if (loading) {
    return <PageLoader />;
  }

  if (user === null) {
    return <Login uiConfig={uiConfig} user={user} userRole={userRole} />;
  }

  if (userRole === null) {
    return <Verification />;
  }

  if (ErrorStatusState > 0 || configdata.maintenance) {
    return (
      <>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <Header />
          <ContentWrapper>
            <MainContentWrapper>
              <AppWrapper>
                <PageWrapper>
                  <MainWrapper>
                    <ErrorClassifyRender
                      ErrorStatus={ErrorStatusState}
                      maintenance={configdata.maintenance}
                    />
                  </MainWrapper>
                </PageWrapper>
              </AppWrapper>
            </MainContentWrapper>
          </ContentWrapper>
        </Provider>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <Header />
      <ContentWrapper>
        <MainContentWrapper>
          <Navigation />
          <AppWrapper>
            <MainApp id="appDiv">
            

              <PageWrapper>
                <MainWrapper>
                  <Routes />
                </MainWrapper>

              </PageWrapper>
            </MainApp>
          </AppWrapper>
        </MainContentWrapper>
      </ContentWrapper>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

the AuthProvider looks like:

```js
import { useEffect, createContext, useState } from "react";
import { isAfter } from "date-fns";
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import axios from "axios";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children, fbconfig }) => {
  const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL || window.location.origin;

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [userRole, setUserRole] = useState(null);
  const [isEmailVerified, setIsEmailVerified] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [verificationLoading, setVerificationLoading] = useState(false);
  const [verifyRequestBlocked, setVerifyRequestBlocked] = useState(false);
  const [emailSent, setEmailSent] = useState(false);
  const [isNewUser, setIsNewUser] = useState(false);
  const [accessTokenExpired, setAccessTokenExpired] = useState(false);

  // Configure Firebase.
  const config = {
    apiKey: fbconfig.FIREABSE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: fbconfig.FIREABSE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: fbconfig.FIREABSE_PROJECT_ID,
  };

  // Configure FirebaseUI.
  if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  const sendEmail = async ({ email, isNewUser = false }) => {
    // setLoading(true);
    setVerificationLoading(true);

    await axios
      .post(`${baseURL}/send_email_verification`, {
        email,
        link: window.location.origin,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.error) {
          setUser(response);
          setEmailSent(true);
          setVerifyRequestBlocked(true);
          setVerificationLoading(false);
        } else {
          setUser(response);
          setEmailSent(true);
          setVerificationLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setVerifyRequestBlocked(true);
        setUser({ data: { email: email } });
        setVerificationLoading(false);
        setEmailSent(true);
      });

    setIsNewUser(isNewUser);
  };

  const uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: "popup",
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    signInSuccessUrl: "/",
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: async (authResult) => {
        if (authResult.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
          await sendEmail({
            isNewUser: true,
            email: authResult.user.email,
          });
        } else {
          setIsNewUser(false);
          setLoading(false);
        }

        return false;
      },
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      setLoading(true);
      if (user === null) {
        setUser(null);
        setLoading(false);
        return;
      }

      if (user.emailVerified) {
        setIsEmailVerified(user.emailVerified);
        await user.getIdToken().then(async (accessToken) => {
          setLoading(true);
          try {
            const result = await axios.post(
              `${baseURL}/user`,
              {
                token: accessToken,
              },
              { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } }
            );

            const expirationTimeInSeconds =
              JSON.parse(atob(accessToken.split(".")[1])).exp * 1000;

            const dateResult = isAfter(
              new Date(),
              new Date(expirationTimeInSeconds)
            );

            if (dateResult) {
              setAccessTokenExpired(true);
            }

            localStorage.setItem("token", accessToken);
            localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(result.data));

            setUser({
              ...result.data,
              token: accessToken,
              status: result.status,
            });
            setUserRole(result.data.role);
            setLoading(false);
          } catch (error) {
            setUser(null);
            setLoading(false);
          }
        });
      } else {
        setUser({ data: user });
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        accessTokenExpired,
        emailSent,
        verifyRequestBlocked,
        isEmailVerified,
        loading,
        userRole,
        uiConfig,
        isNewUser,
        verificationLoading,
        sendEmail,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

and one of the endpoint calls are like:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import ReactEcharts from "echarts-for-react";
import {
  fetchHistory,
} from "../../Redux";


const History = (props) => {
  const barRef = useRef();

  const {
    brand,
    parentStartDate,
    parentEndDate,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    selectedId,
    tabID,
    showTabs,
    showComponent,
    detailed,
    graphs,
    tooltipExtra,
  } = props;

  const predict_data_response = useSelector((state) => state.History.predict_data);


  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(
        fetchHistoryroi({
          brand: brand.name,
          parentStartDate,
          parentEndDate,
          componentName,
          tabID,
          nestedObjects,
        })
      );
  }, [parentStartDate, parentEndDate]);




  const predict_data = ResponseFilter({ responseFilterProps });


  const options = {
    toolbox: getToolBox(),
    textStyle: {
      color: colors.white,
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: (params) => {
        return getTooltip({
          params,
          avarage,
          devider,
          componentName: "History",
        });
      },
      backgroundColor: colors.cardBg,
      extraCssText: extraCssText,
    },
    grid: {
      left: "7px",
      right: "7px",
      bottom: "3%",
      containLabel: true,
    },
    xAxis: [
      {
        axisLabel: {
          fontSize: 10,
        },
        type: "category",
        data: labels,
        axisTick: {
          alignWithLabel: true,
        },
      },
      {
        axisLabel: {
          fontSize: 10,
        },
        position: "bottom",
        offset: 15,
        axisLine: {
          show: false,
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false,
        },
        data: labelsValues,
      },
    ],
    yAxis: [
      {
        axisLabel: {
          fontSize: 10,
          formatter: (value, index) => {
            return value;
          },
        },
        splitLine: {
          lineStyle: {
            color: colors.lightGray,
          },
        },
        type: "value",
      },
    ],
    series: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        label: {
          show: true,
          position: ["30%", "30%"],
          formatter: ({ data }) => {
            const { value } = data;
            return value === avarage / devider && avarage !== 0 ? "NA" : "";
          },
        },
        barMaxWidth: 40,
        data: nums,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <ContainerWrapper>
     <ReactEcharts
       ref={barRef}
       option={options}
       data-test="HistoryGraph"/>      
    </ContainerWrapper>
  );
};

export default History;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

this is the image on what happens when someone click a link after an hour inactiviy

[image]

any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the access token directly, the Firebase SDK provides [`User#getIdTokenResult()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getidtokenresult) which provides the metadata of the token along with the token itself.

```
const { token, expirationTime } = await firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult();
```

Instead of storing the access token in the object you are passing to `setUser()`, a better option would be to add a Axios request interceptor, like you are doing for the responses. This will allow you to trigger requests using Axios as you normally would, but you don't have to add `` { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` } } `` on every request.

The following `useEffect()` attaches an interceptor on mount and detaches it on unmount, where the interceptor attaches the user's latest ID token to the request. Here, I've also added a clause where if the token were to expire in the next 5 minutes, it's forcefully refreshed.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const authRequestInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) {
    if (!config.url.startsWith(baseURL))
      return config; // this request doesn't target our API, leave untouched

    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (currentUser === null)
      return config; // no user signed in, return config unmodified

    // getIdTokenResult provides token metadata in the result
    // will return current token, unless it's expired where a fresh token is grabbed
    let { token, expirationTime } = await currentUser.getIdTokenResult();

    const expiresMS = (new Date(expirationTime)).getTime();
    if (expiresMS - Date.now() < 300000) {
      // if the token will expire in the next 5 minutes, 
      // forcefully grab a fresh token
      token = await currentUser.getIdToken(true);
    }

    // Attach the token to the request
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;

    return config;
  });

  return () => axios.interceptors.request.eject(authRequestInterceptor);
}, []);
```

**Note:** You should use the same `useEffect()` strategy for your response interceptor and you should use `return firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(...)` so that the cleanup function returned by `onAuthStateChanged` is accessible to its `useEffect()`.

Comment: Probably AuthProvider because it's Auth related. Honestly you can put it wherever you want.